# Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller in iPad

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

```
-(id)init
{
if (self = [super init]) 
{
    self.dmrPlaylists = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];
     }
}
-(void)dealloc
{   
[self.dmrPlaylists release];
}
-(DMRPlaylist *)getDMRPlaylistByUUID:(NSString *)deviceUUID
{
if (deviceUUID == nil)
    return nil;

for(int i = 0; i < self.dmrPlaylists.count; i++)
{
    DMRPlaylist * dmrPlaylist = [self.dmrPlaylists objectAtIndex:i];
    if([dmrPlaylist.deviceUUID isEqualToString:deviceUUID])
    {
        return dmrPlaylist;
    }
}

return nil;
}
```

Memory(Core Foundation/Object-C) Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ....which line?  Also, how is your dmrPlaylists property declared?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * dmrPlaylists; yes ,the warning on[self.dmrPlaylists release];                           -(void)dealloc
{ 
 //[self.dmrPlaylists release];
 [delegateList release];
 free(_dmrStateChangeNotifier);
 [super dealloc];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do not use `self.dmrPlaylists` in your `init` and `dealloc` methods.  Instead, interact with the underlying variable.

2) Call `[super dealloc]`

Without knowing which line the warning is on, can't be sure, but these are problems.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * dmrPlaylists; yes ,the warning on[self.dmrPlaylists release];

Comment: dmrPlaylists is init with autorelease,is that means there is no need to release  dmrPlaylists in dealloc method?

Comment: You need to use dmrPlaylists, not self.dmrPlaylists (i.e. the backing instance variable that you synthesize) in init and dealloc or some undefined behavior could happen.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what part of the above code causes the error. Step through it with the debugger to isolate where it happens and get back to us.

Also, you haven't given us enough code to know what's wrong. For example:

```
self.dmrPlaylists = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];
```

probably ultimately calls `-setDmrPlaylists:` with an autoreleased mutable array. Where is `-setDmrPlaylists:` defined? Is it declared by a `@property` statement and `@synthesize`ed? If so, is it declared as a `retain` property? If not, then the setter will never call `retain` on the mutable array. And when the `autorelease` decrements the mutable array's retain count at the end of the event loop, it will likely be deallocated leaving you pointing at junk memory.